# Objective C "callback"

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, object, callback

i'm new in Objective C. Now i'm developing my new app and i have some questions about callback functions.

So this is my scenario:

I have a NSObject class called Person that represents (obviously) to a person.
This class have some parameters like: person name, person second name, etc.
In Person.m i have a function that calls to my rest API, retrieve all data what i need, parse JSON response, create Person objects and insert it to NSMutableArray.
Here is an example of my Person.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, assign) id delegate;


@property NSString * name;
@property NSString * secondName;


-(void)getPersons;

@end
```

And Person.m file:

```
#import "Person.h"
#import <AFNetworking.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation Person
@synthesize delegate;

// Call this function to get all persons
-(void)getPersons{

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"www.myApi.com/persons" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSMutableArray *allPersons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        // Parsing JSON response and getting array with all persons
        allPersons = [self parseaJson:responseObject];
        // Calling my "callback" function in my ViewController.m
        [self.delegate callback:allPersons];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

// This function will parse json response and create array with Person objects
-(NSMutableArray *)parseaJson:(NSDictionary *)jsonResponse{
    NSMutableArray *allPersons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *resources = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"resources"];

    for (NSDictionary *jsonObject in resources) {
        Person *personObject = [[Person alloc]init];
        personObject.name = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"name"];
        personObject.secondName = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"secondname"];

        [allPersons addObject:personObject];
    }

    return allPersons;
}

@end
```

Also i have my ViewController class. From my ViewController class i'm calling to my Person class to get all Person objects in one array.
Here is an example of ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    /**
     Array with all Person objects
     */
    NSMutableArray * personsArray;
}


/**
 This function calls when Person.m have finished to retrive all persons from my API
*/
-(void)callback:(NSMutableArray *)recivedPersons;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *table;

@end
```

And ViewController.m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Person.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.table.delegate = self;
    self.table.dataSource = self;


    // GETTING ALL PERSONS
    Person * myPersonClass = [[Person alloc]init];
    [myPersonClass getPersons];
    myPersonClass.delegate = self; // This line is very important...
}

-(void)callback:(NSMutableArray *)recivedPersons{

    personsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:lineasBus];
    // Reloading my table
    [self.table reloadData];

}
...
@end
```

So, this works as follow:

1. From ViewController.m i'm calling my getPersons function in Person.m
2. After getting JSON response i'm parsing it and create array with Person objects
3. Call "callback" function in ViewController.m

All of this works because I use delegate but really, i don't know what is delegate...
I think that there is an alternative and more professional way to implement solutions like in my case. 
(Maybe blocks or something like this ?)

Comment: To learn more about delegation and protocols you should read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: I'm not sure why so many people are in love with delegation in IOS. Sure you have to use it sometimes, but when writing code for an app with 10s of thousands of lines of code, delegation can turn your code base into a dependency nightmare. Sure, it's important to use delegation when Apple has this set up in their UIKit elements, but you don't really have to employ your own custom delegates at all. In fact, I've written apps with 50k+ lines of code using custom delegation zero times. I'd post an answer here to help you out, but there are too many brain dead devs on stack who love delegation.

Comment: continuation .. and would love to downvote me because they don't know how to subclass correctly and use advanced setters/getters and C block operations to avoid using delegation. Apple's own delegation stuff is useful, but I'm serious when I say this, you don't really need to use it outside of this if you learn to code IOS from a very intense CLang perspective and stick to this structure: don't use storyboards, create all your views programatically, encapsulate your code to the point of each view controller only holds control code for a separate view, all view code is contained in separate  ..

Comment: subclass files, for example, you have EXViewController.h and EXViewController.m which uses EXView.h and EXView.m and EXView uses EXButtonSubClass.h and EXButtonSubClass.m and EXView also uses EXCustomTextField.h and EXCustomTextField.m, etc, etc, subclassing to the point of everything being within its own universe while passing values using custom getters and setters that flow from the view controller init methods down to the subviews and filling out all information from there. Delegation is a cheap way to get around this, but it's also a terribly inelegant solution.

Comment: A "delegate" is merely an object which you can call upon to provide data or perform certain functions.  It provides isolation between the data/functions and the code utilizing it, such that they can be developed and maintained separately, and so that excessive inter-dependencies are avoided.  It's not magic.  And like any programming concept it can be overused or used inappropriately.

Comment: But are delegate in my case is a right solution ? Also i created another NSObject class and another ...ViewController and i use the same code like in example, but now i see strange stuff like when i am calling NSObject class from another ViewController also it calls my Person class. I don't know why it happens so i think that this is because i'm using bad delegate.

Comment: This isn't really a normal place to use delegates.  It's also weird that your method to retrieve all your persons is an instance method on your model class.  I would either move your method to a separate service class or make it a class method.  I would also remove the delegate and have it take a completion handler block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what i normally do.
On Person.h

```
+ (void)personsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *result, NSError *error))completion;
```

On your Person.m

```
+ (void)personsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *result, NSError *error))completion{

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"www.myApi.com/persons" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSMutableArray *allPersons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        // Parsing JSON response and getting array with all persons
        allPersons = [self parseaJson:responseObject];

//here you call the completion handler
if(completion) completion(allPersosn, error);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

And you use it from a VC

```
[Person personsWithCompletion:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow ! You are right, thank you ! This is exactly what i wanted ! It's like promises in JavaScript.